# Passing id as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that contains of multiple divs, each div has an ID that comes from the database, in each div there is a like button, what i want to do is when i click on the like button to pass the ID as a parameter in my function, here is what i have tried so far:

```js
function addLike
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myID" onClick="addLike()">
<button type="button">Like</button>
</div>

<div id="myID" onClick="addLike()">
<button type="button">Like</button>
</div>

<div id="myID" onClick="addLike()">
<button type="button">Like</button>
</div>

<div id="myID" onClick="addLike()">
<button type="button">Like</button>
</div>

<div id="myID" onClick="addLike()">
<button type="button">Like</button>
</div>

<div id="myID" onClick="addLike()">
<button type="button">Like</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ids in the document should be unique.

Comment: @lilezek As OP mentioned, IDs are coming from DB so I guess they are unique. I think, in code, it's just for illustration.

Comment: 1) `id` attributes must be unique, although I assume they are in your code as they're coming from a database. 2) Put the click handler on the `button`. It makes very little sense putting the click handler on the parent of the element that's supposed to be clicked. 3) http://api.jquery.com/click

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifier

Answer (score 1):

The IDs must be unique.

Whenever you define an inline click event handler you may consider to pass the following two variables:

- **this**: current element
- **event**: the event object

```js
function addLike(ele, e) {
    console.log('ID: ' + ele.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="myID1" onclick="addLike(this, event)">
    <button type="button">Like</button>
</div>

<div id="myID2" onclick="addLike(this, event)">
    <button type="button">Like</button>
</div>

<div id="myID3" onclick="addLike(this, event)">
    <button type="button">Like</button>
</div>

<div id="myID4" onclick="addLike(this, event)">
    <button type="button">Like</button>
</div>

<div id="myID5" onclick="addLike(this, event)">
    <button type="button">Like</button>
</div>

<div id="myID6" onclick="addLike(this, event)">
    <button type="button">Like</button>
</div>
```

Comment: P.S: you don't necessarily need to pass the `event`. 1. cause in this specific case is useless. 2. cause you can use `event` even without passing it as parameter.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I know. The best way is to use addEventListener or jquery on. It's only an answer. The best approach is to avoid at all the inline code. Moreover, because I don't know the usage.....I said: you may and not you need. I agree with you. Believe me. Thank you very much for your hints.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to remove onClick from your divs:

```
<div id="myID">
```

and insert onclick in every button:

```
<button onclick="addLike(this.parent.id)">
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can only have one ID in a page. So I would first advise you use class instead of IDs. Now if you prefer to use IDs then each of the IDs should be unique. You should then have

```
<div id="id1" onClick="addLike(this.id)"></div>
<div id="id2" onClick="addLike(this.id)"></div>
```

Comment: by using `this.id` you're just limiting yourself. Simply pass `this` and than within the function use whatever property you like / need.

Comment: Thanks bro! Good one

Answer (score 0):

Okay as far as i can see you are trying to make a like button.
For that i would suggest that instead of giving id to a `<button>` as its value.
And for the button action you have to create a form whose action will be on some other PHP or any other server side language. So for your problem here is the solution.

```
<form action="like.php" method="POST">
 <div id="myid1">
  <button value="myid1" name="button1">LIKE</button>
 </div> 
<div id="myid2">
  <button value="myid2" name="button2">LIKE</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Now when you want to pass the value to a function then you can use the value of the button by its respective name attribute. You need to have different name for each button.

Comment: **Its' 2017**. can you eventually suggest some AJAX as superset on your `form` fallback , instead of *simply* pointing a user to some `like.php` page...

Comment: sorry i am a newbie to AJAX. Don't have an idea about it. I can tell you the php script